# Doesn't see a bean using Autowired annotation, nothing helps

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to autowire the Service in my Spring MVC app and it always fails! Tried everything from every question on the Internet but I couldn't find the answer. The problem is that Spring actually can't autowire field and says there is no such bean,

Tried everything, changing the code, configuration, etc. Maybe for now everything in my project is too messed up and I can't find the bug.

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;


    public void setUserService(IUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").
            addAnnotatedClass(User.class).addAnnotatedClass(Restaurant.class).
            buildSessionFactory();

    public UserServiceImpl() {
    }
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvcdemo.Controller" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <absolute-ordering />
    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvcdemo.Services" />
</beans>
```

```
Error creating bean with name 'viewController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.springmvcdemo.Services.IUserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Show the project structure. BTW, why do you have `UserServiceImpl` annotated as `@Component` and `@Service`? (only one should suffice)

Comment: Your application is initialized upon `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, where `UserServiceImpl` is not covered by component-scan (base package is different)

Comment: when adding userservice package to component scan in dispatcher-servlet.xml i get this error: `[C:\Users\jkdev\IdeaProjects\SpringMVC\out\artifacts\SpringMVC\WEB-INF\classes\com\springmvcdemo\Services\UserServiceImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.springmvcdemo.Services.UserServiceImpl`

Comment: You should use Spring to set up your session factory and inject it into your service instead of creating it as a static field. Maybe when this class is loaded, the session factory causes an exception which means the class cannot be initialized.

Comment: @BretC thanks for advice, i'll try this one

Comment: @BretC this actually worked for me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that the `SessionFactory` was being constructed in a static field of the service.

The class could be found, but there was some error creating the session factory which is why the error message contains "Instantiation of bean failed".

Moving the session factory to be managed by Spring and then injecting it was the way to go.